# Error 310: Staging failed deploying - Grails app in Cloud Foundry

Tags: mysql, grails, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy my grails app to Cloud Foundry and I'm getting the eror below.

I'm wondering if my mysql datasource is correctly configured in DataSource.groovy and this could be causing the issue or I'm missing something else.

====> /logs/staging.log <====
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (116K): OK
Push Status: OK
Staging Application: ..Error 310: Staging failed: 'Staging plugin failed staging application:
 /var/vcap/packages/stager/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.44/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:25:in `block in stage_application': Web application staging failed: web.xml not found (RuntimeError)
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.44/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:19:in`chdir'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/stager/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/vcap_staging-0.1.44/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:19:in `stage_application'
    from /var/vcap/packages/stager/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in`'
'

I tried to run **grails cf-list-files** to check tomcat logs but I got the following error:

| Environment set to development.....
Error: 400 Bad Request
| Error org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryException: 400 Bad Request (Operation not permitted on a stopped app)
| Error     at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient$ErrorHandler.handleError(CloudFoundryClient.java:78)
| Error     at org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.CloudFoundryClient.getFile(CloudFoundryClient.java:463)

Comment: If you're using the grails cloud foundry plugin, it would overwrite your datasources for you when it binds the connection. This error seems to indicate that it can't find web.xml.

Comment: grails install-plugin cloud-foundry followed by grails cf-push

Answer (score 1):

As tomas posted on 3/27,

> grails install-plugin cloud-foundry followed by grails cf-push

Comment: I'm encountering this problem with AppFog and the cloud-foundry plugin doesn't address the issue.  I can get it to push to AppFog but still have the 310 error associated with web.xml.  I can see that the web.xml file is there.