# Error 310: Staging failed, web.xml not found

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry, appfog

I'm moving a Grails application from CouldFoundry to AppFog and I'm encountering an Error 310: Staging failed, web.xml not found. The **af push** is successful but when I try to set an environment variable with **env-add** or start the app I get the staging error.

There's a previous response to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882391/error-310-staging-failed-deploying-grails-app-in-cloud-foundry). I tried installing the latest cloud-foundry plugin as described in that response and the cf-push successfully pushes the app to AppFog but I still get the 310 error.

```
Error 310: Staging failed: 'Staging task failed:
 Staging plugin failed: /opt/cloudfoundry/vcap/staging/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:28:in `block in stage_application': Web application staging failed: web.xml not found (RuntimeError)  
from /opt/cloudfoundry/vcap/staging/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:22:in `chdir'
from /opt/cloudfoundry/vcap/staging/lib/vcap/staging/plugin/java_web/plugin.rb:22:in `stage_application'
from /opt/cloudfoundry/vcap/stager/bin/run_plugin:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm also using Intellij Idea and tried the solution suggested [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Staging-WEB-INF-web-xml-could-not-be-found-td1317912.html) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was inadvertently including Tomcat in my WAR file as described by Graeme in this [post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Error-deploying-2-1-0-war-to-tomcat6-td4631449.html). When I corrected the Tomcat reference, the staging error was resolved (it was no longer looking for the web.xml file associated with Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and resolved it by renaming the war file to the same name as the application I created on appfog AND running "af update " in the target directory.  For some reason, I had been running "af update" without the  and I believe that might have been the problem.  Anyway, I'm not exactly sure which change worked, but I was able to get my application running after following these steps.

```
$ grails war target/rw.war
| Packaging Grails application
| Compiling 2 source files..
| Done creating WAR target/rw.war
$ cd target/
$ af update rw
```